# ORA-01861 error

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am trying to insert data from Netezza to Oracle.Here are my inserts as below.But they don't work and throw me the above error.

```
INSERT INTO AM_CTL_DDS_LOAD values('ALB',1002,'2012/02/12');
INSERT INTO AM_CTL_DDS_LOAD values('ALB',1002,'2012/02/09');
INSERT INTO AM_CTL_DDS_LOAD values('ALB',1002,'2012/02/21');
INSERT INTO AM_CTL_DDS_LOAD values('ALB',1002,'2012/02/23');
```

My table structure is as below.

```
CREATE TABLE AM_CTL_DDS_LOAD
(
    MAS_DIV_CD VARCHAR(5),
    LD_SEQ_NBR INTEGER NOT NULL,
    TUNING_DT DATE NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Would you mind giving us a quick overview of the table structure please?

Comment: ORA-01861 is related to problems due to format strings (http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01861.php). It looks like you're trying to force strings into a date fields, but it's hard to tell without a DDL of AM_CTL_DDS_LOAD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ORA-01861: literal does not match format string` error implies that the third column of the `AM_CTL_DDS_LOAD` table is defined as a `DATE`, not a `VARCHAR2`, and that the implicit conversion of the string to a date is failing because your session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` isn't 'YYYY/MM/DD'.  The best way to solve the problem is to explicitly insert a `DATE` rather than a `VARCHAR2` by explicitly calling `TO_DATE` with an appropriate format mask.

```
INSERT INTO AM_CTL_DDS_LOAD values('ALB',1002,to_date('2012/02/12', 'YYYY/MM/DD') );
INSERT INTO AM_CTL_DDS_LOAD values('ALB',1002,to_date('2012/02/09', 'YYYY/MM/DD') );
INSERT INTO AM_CTL_DDS_LOAD values('ALB',1002,to_date('2012/02/21', 'YYYY/MM/DD') );
INSERT INTO AM_CTL_DDS_LOAD values('ALB',1002,to_date('2012/02/23', 'YYYY/MM/DD') );
```